# Create a schedule programmatically

Tags: akka, quartz-scheduler

I am using akka-quartz-scheduler to schedule jobs that trigger Akka actors.

Example code:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ActorSystem", config);
QuartzSchedulerExtensionscheduler =
    (QuartzSchedulerExtension) QuartzSchedulerExtension.get(system);
ActorRef jobActor =
    system.actorOf(FromConfig.getInstance().props(Props.create(JobActor.class)), "job_actor");

scheduler.schedule("Job1", jobActor, "Job1");
```

Getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching quartz configuration found for schedule 'Job1'
```

Does this mean that for every job, I need to add the schedule in the configuration? Is there a programmatic way of doing this?

Comment: Configuration is needed not for every job, but for [every schedule](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler#schedule-configuration), like `Every30Seconds`.